# how to insert data in Cassandra with custom datatype?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have created table for users with following query using cqlsh command line.
Use case is to store company_id with role_id for every users in users table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE users (id uuid PRIMARY KEY,name text,company list<frozen<map<uuid, set<uuid>>>>)
```

Now, I want to insert data in this table. I'm using following query to insert data, but I'm getting syntactical errors.

```
insert into users (id,name, company) VALUES (now(),'darshana', [12f64b58-423f-408b-a6e5-42c69208511b:[{12f64b58-423f-408b-a6e5-42c69208511b}]]);
```

I have tried several solutions but none worked for me.

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 3):

The following syntax should work:

```
insert into users (id, name, company) VALUES ( 
  now(), 'darshana', 
  [{12f64b58-423f-408b-a6e5-42c69208511b:{12f64b58-423f-408b-a6e5-42c69208511b}}]
);
```

List literals are enclosed in [], maps and sets in {}. Look for set_literal in http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html.